# Нужно ли обособлять "как данность"?

Tags: пунктуация, как

Евросоюз должен принять как данность результаты референдума.

Answer (score 2):

Обособлять не нужно, поскольку по смыслу здесь выражается не сравнение, а тождественность: не способ "принятия" здесь сопоставляется с тем, как принимают нечто другое (принял его, как/словно родного), а предлагается считать результаты "данностью", т. е. они предлагаются к принятию ***в качестве*** данности (свершившегося факта или решения, которое уже не изменить).

> Розенталь Д. Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке для
>   работников печати
>
> http://www.gumer.info/bibliotek_Buks/Linguist/rozent1/03.php
>
> § 115 Сравнительный оборот
>
> п. 3. Обороты с союзом как не выделяются запятыми:
>
> 3) если союз как имеет значение «в качестве»...